# How can I ensure all data sent from an Arduino is received by a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: serial, arduino

I am using an Arduino Uno to sample a signal. I then want to send those samples in a block to the Raspberry Pi. At the moment I am simply using

**(on the Arduino side)**
Within loop

```
Serial.write(value)
```

**(on the Raspberry Pi side, in python)**

```
import Serial
fromArd = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
while True:
    try:
       val = ord(fromArd.read())
       print(val)
```

This results in some values going missing (due to work queuing). Does anyone know how I can make sure the RasPi receives ALL the data it is sent?

I've used MPICH Message Passing Interface before but the Arduino doesn't have an OS, so I'm not sure how I can use it or if it would work.

Is there possibly another way of doing this by only sending data when the RasPi is willing to read it? Would this be interrupt driven or based on polling every time I want data to be sent?

Thanks,
E.Lee

**Extra explanation**: 
I know that some data was 'missed' or 'dropped' because the input to the Arduino was a sine wave and when I plot the results from the RaspberryPi there are phase changes in the sine wave. For example the values are slowly increasing then suddenly become zero and start to increase again. OR One cycle is measured as expected but the next cycle does not line up.

The RaspberryPi is not a real time device. My suspicion is that when I send data to it while it's doing other things (eg GPU) it doesn't read the data.

I looked at the data coming out of the Arduino when connected to my laptop - the wave form was exactly as expected so I think it is an issue with RasPi rather than Arduino.

Comment: I don't really understand how RaspberryPi can miss some data in your case. Could you explain some more?

Comment: I've added more explanation in the question now.

Comment: You are sending your data at very low speed and serial data should be buffered by kernel so unless RapsberryPi is **realy** very busy, it shouldn't drop anything.

Comment: I aim to send data at 10kHz but found this problem at only 100Hz.

Comment: How busy is really busy? Do you know how I can reduce how busy it is?

Comment: Your baud rate on serial is set to 9600. This means you can only send 9600 bits per second. How can you send 100kHz or even 10kHz using this speed? And by "really busy" I mean that CPU is loaded to 100% and there are couple of processes always waiting for CPU.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me. I'm sending 2 bytes per sample so the maximum (without problem) I should be able to reach is 600Hz. I had a problem at 100Hz. In the future I'll need to use at least 160,000 baud rate but that doesn't explain the problem at 100Hz does it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to start troubleshooting from the other end, from the beginning of data. Make sure your adruino really captures your sine wave fully. I suspect, when your duino is sending the block of freshly captured data the capture routine is not called and this results in missing samples.

Besides that, there are time proven data control signals used in serial transfers, XON/XOFF in software or RTS/CTS in hardware. Use them.

Comment: I also suspected that was the case but I was able to confirm it wasn't, by looking at the output from the Arduino (via the serial monitor provided by Arduino software). I use a timer interrupt to sample data so I wasn't sure how it would cope if I was sending data while the interrupt occurred. However, as I mentioned, I can get the expected data using my own laptop.

I'll look into XON/XOFF and let you know if it fixes the issue, thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: Lenik could you perhaps link me to a good tutorial/website with regards to XON/XOFF? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need flow control.  Here's a hardware way to do it:
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=18813.0